# Is there a way to set Safari's homepage to an entire bookmark folder?

Tags: safari, catalina

I want all the pages to open in different tabs automatically. When I tried opening the bookmark and choosing "Set to current page" in Settings it only set it to the one tab I was actively viewing, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a 'Favourites' category.

You can then either right click and 'Open in New Tabs' or from Bookmarks menu, 'Show Favourites'.

From the Safari Sidebar you can drag & drop to Different folders. Add a folder to Favourites & use that.

Comment: That's what I'm doing for now but I'm looking for a more automatic way that doesn't require me to click anything.

Comment: Don't close them. They'll re-open next launch. I can't think of anything else without needing mind-reading technology to know when you may need them next.